# Setting up flycheck in pair with different mode is not working

Tags: flycheck

For the SQL-mode I use the package [Sqlint](https://github.com/purcell/sqlint) with Flycheck. This works fine. Now I switched to the package [EDBI](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-edbi) which is an database interface for Emacs. There is a query editor built-in.  I would like to tell flycheck that he must syntax-check the query editor with the help of the SQL-lint.

The major mode of the query editor is `edbi:sql-mode`.

After reading the well written documentation of flycheck, I have set it up as following:

```
(eval-after-load 'flycheck
  '(progn
     (flycheck-add-mode 'sqlint 'edbi:sql-mode)))
```

After evaluating it and creating a new buffer, Flycheck doesn't have any checker in the `edbi:sql-mode`, as <kbd>M-x</kbd> `flycheck-verify-setup` tells me the following:

> Syntax checkers for buffer *edbi:query-editor 1 * in edbi:sql-mode:
>
> There are no syntax checkers for this buffer!
>
> Flycheck Mode is disabled.

I wonder why flycheck doesn't use sqlint in `edbi:sql-mode`? It's set up following  the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether that's just a typo in your question but there's no `sqlint` syntax checker in Flycheck.  It's name is `sql-sqlint`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it in my configuration from `sqlint` to `sql-sqlint`. And it gives the desired effect. It's somewhat confusing that the package is called `sqlint`, but the checker is actually `sql-sqlint`, which caused to this issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ReneFroger The prefix denotes the language the tool checks.  We had it for better ordering and documentation.  Note that we document all syntax checker names comprehensively in our manual.  If you are unsure about a checker name you can look it up 